# Black screen after installing vboxvideo module on guest Kubuntu 17.04

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

After installing vboxvideo module, I can only access console using Host+F1 thru F6. I keep getting a black screen instead of regular UI. I even tried to upgrade to 17.10 without any change.
My environment is Host Windows 10 v.1709 Host Kubuntu 17.04/17.10

Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you press ALT+F2, does the searchbar come up? Can you switch to the terminal with CTRL+ALT+F1 and back with CTRL+ALT+F7?
I've had this problem multiple times with Kubuntu where the plasma crashes and you can't get your actual desktop or widgets to show up. I've heard deleting caches or uninstalling plasma sometimes fixes the problem. But I've been best off with fresh installing the whole operating system.

I'd recommend switching to KDE Neon. It's essentially the same as Kubuntu except this distro uses the LTS version of Ubuntu such that KDE applications are more stable.